# Multivariate hypergeometric distribution with non-equal class probabilities

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

**How to generalize the Multivariate hypergeometric distribution when the initial probability distribution of classes in the initial population is not uniform, i.e. some classes are more likely to be chosen.**

I came across this question when dealing with the following scenario:

*A sneaker shop has a large shelf full of boxes of different size sneakers. On the shelf there are a total of 225 individual boxes with pairs of different sizes, distributed randomly. There are 46 pairs of size 43, 38 pairs of size 44, 69 pairs of size 45 and 72 pairs of size 46. You are given N picks. What is the probability of getting K pairs of sneakers size 45?*

This made me think of a multivariate hypergeoemtric distribution, but the initial probability distribution of chosing each size of sneakers is not uniform.

Could anyone guide me in the right direction on how to formally model this kind of problem? The answer might be obvious, but my statistics skills lack profoundly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

First simplify the problem to a hypergeometric distribution with  $69$ pairs of size $45$, and $156$ pairs of "others".

> I take it that from a practical viewpoint, you want **exactly** $K$ pairs ($= K$ boxes) of size $45$, as evidently you are a bulk buyer, and having got the number of size $45$ pairs, it would be better to buy other sizes

> Thus $Pr = \Large\frac{\binom{69}{K}\binom{156}{N-K}}{\binom{225}{N}}$

Comment: Thank you, it is quite obvious to think of it. But what if instead of a 1 vs all case, the problem would ask for exactly C_i elements of each class? Would a hypergeometric distribution still work?

Comment: Yes, it would work. suppose there were $5$ red balls, $4$ blue balls and $3$ green balls, and you wanted $2$ of each, $Pr= \Large\frac{\binom52\binom42\binom32}{\binom{12}6}$

Comment: @AndreiPrioteasa: Thank you, and do remember that if any answer serves your purpose, you should tick it, so that it gets closed as answered, and also shows your appreciation for those who have taken time to answer your question. Cheers ! $\;\;$ :)